# How to create a GUID/UUID using iOS

Tags: ios, uuid, guid

I want to be able to create a GUID/UUID on the iPhone and iPad.

The intention is to be able to create keys for distributed data that are all unique. Is there a way to do this with the iOS SDK?

Comment: There's an article about how to ensure you never lose that generated UUID, even for iOS 5 and later using the KeyChain. https://blog.onliquid.com/persistent-device-unique-identifier-ios-keychain/

Answer (score 325, accepted):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Returns the Unique ID of your iPhone.

> EDIT: `-[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` is now deprecated and apps are being rejected from the App Store for using it. The method below is now the preferred approach.

If you need to create several UUID, just use this method (with ARC):

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
  CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
  CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
  CFRelease(theUUID);
  return (__bridge NSString *)string;
}
```

EDIT: Jan, 29 2014:
If you're targeting iOS 6 or later, you can now use the much simpler method:

```
NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] has been deprecated as of iOS 5, and Apple is now rejecting apps that use it (as of March 2012). The rest of the response is still accurate.

Comment: Having been around this question for a while, I'm pretty sure the original question wasn't about the device's unique identifier, but about just getting a useful general unique identifier for something.

Comment: To make this ARC compliant you must cast the string object and remove the autorelease call. In other words add the cast: NSString* string = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);

Comment: As of iOS 6 you can use: NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

Comment: Is the auto-release needed? Xcode complains about it when I run "Analyze", that's all. It says "Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected"|

Comment: The correct answer for iOS5 and 6 with XCode 4 or later is nanshi's getUUID implementation.

Comment: If i use [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]; in iOS7 and above, won't my app rejected by Apple?

Comment: Any idea how to use this in swift?

Comment: iOS9:  NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]                          UUID always results in 'nil' why is this?

Comment: @Quadrivium I just used it on an iOS 8 + 9 app and it works just fine. I even re-tested it for you a minute ago :)

Comment: @Whoami No Apple won't reject your app because of this. That code just generates a unique id and nothing more (and one unique id every time you call it). It is not the device's unique id.

Comment: Xcode reports potential leak with the first example, and suggests using `CFBridgingRelease`:

`CFUUIDRef UUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef stringUUID = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, UUID);
CFRelease(UUID);
return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(stringUUID);`

Answer (score 101):

Here is the simple code I am using, compliant with ARC.

```
+(NSString *)getUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    NSString * uuidString = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);
    CFRelease(newUniqueId);

    return uuidString;
}
```

Comment: Honestly this should be the accepted answer, the original question asked for a GUID or UUID generator, and everyone responded with how to obtain the phone's UDID.  A Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) and Unique Device Identifier (UDID) are not the same thing.

Comment: here is a straight line one 
NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

Answer (score 93):

In iOS 6 you can easily use:

```
NSUUID  *UUID = [NSUUID UUID];
NSString* stringUUID = [UUID UUIDString];
```

More details in [Apple's Documentations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution.  If you don't have to support prior to iOS 6, use this.  I was using core data generated permanent IDs, but this is much better. +1

Comment: Perfect, thank you for this! This is my +1 answer for the day :)

Comment: It change every time I run app in simulator.

Answer (score 46):

Reviewing the Apple Developer documentation I found the [CFUUID](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html) object is available on the iPhone OS 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 24):

In **Swift**:

```
var uuid: String = NSUUID().UUIDString
println("uuid: \(uuid)")
```

Answer (score 22):

The simplest technique is to use `NSString *uuid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]`. See the [NSProcessInfo](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000316-globallyUniqueString) class reference.

Comment: That returns a unique identifier for the process. It has no resemblance to a GUID. From the docs: "The ID includes the host name, process ID, and a time stamp, which ensures that the ID is unique for the network"

Comment: You could be right. It's a pragmatic one-liner, and probably isn't as bulletproof as CFUUID. Anyone who needs the greater rigour ought to drop down to CoreFoundation.

Answer (score 20):

In **Swift 3.0**

```
var uuid = UUID().uuidString
```

Answer (score 7):

I've uploaded my simple but fast implementation of a Guid class for ObjC here: [obj-c GUID](https://code.google.com/p/objc-guid/source/browse/)

```
Guid* guid = [Guid randomGuid];
NSLog("%@", guid.description);
```

It can parse to and from various string formats as well.