# Getting phone UUID through iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

Does the SDK provide an API for retrieving the current phone's UUID?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Comment: Yes - I saw that from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427180/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-using-the-iphone-sdk but the OP was asking how to generate a new UUID, not get the phone's UUID.  It threw me off.  Thanks.

Comment: This is deprecated now. So far I've `CFUUIDRef`, but no Cocoa counterpart…