# iPhone DEV GUID question

Tags: iphone, guid

I would like to know if it is possible, and if it's ok with apple if my app will use the iPhone's GUID with my server, as I don't want to nag my users for User/Passwords ...
Thanks !

Comment: There are various answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427180/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-using-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: It isn't a GUID. It's called a UDID and is 160 bits in length (a GUID would be 128 bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple is crazy about privacy and UDID still allows to differentiate devices etc so I suggest to calculate some hash for example md5 and only afterward to pass it to the server. Such approach will guaranty privacy to your users even if your DB will be compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Apple generally allows this and a lot of analytics frameworks use the device ID for tracking purposes.

You should however consider whether your users' data contains any personal information. If this is the case, I would strongly recommend against using device IDs for identification as they might not be really secret, e.g. because other developers need users' device IDs for beta testing etc. Also, other developers transmit device IDs to *their* servers and could use those to get at personal information from *your* users.

See [this article](http://corte.si/posts/security/openfeint-udid-deanonymization/) for a concrete example of how device IDs could be abused.

Comment: My app won't be using any openFeint or such services. I just want to spare my users the bother. Would it impose an issue on apple's side ?

Comment: Wow, I guess I was too tired yesterday to actually realize how vulnerable this all is. Thanks for that piece of information, it actually is quite disturbing on the user end.