# How do I create a CFUUID NSString under ARC that doesn't leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

There are a couple good examples on SO about CFUUID, notably this one:

[How to create a GUID/UUID using the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427180/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-using-the-iphone-sdk)

But it was made for pre-ARC code, and I'm not a CF junkie (yet), so can someone provide example code that works with ARC?

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
  CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
  CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
  CFRelease(theUUID);
  return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want a "bridged transfer":

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
  CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
  CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
  CFRelease(theUUID);
  return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)string;
}
```

The [Transitioning to ARC Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) says

> `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease()` moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC.

*However*! You should also rename your method. ARC uses method name conventions to reason about retain counts, and methods that start with `get` in Cocoa have a specific meaning involving passing a buffer in for it to get filled with data. A better name would be `buildUUID` or another word that describes the use of the UUID: `pizzaUUID` or `bearUUID`.

Comment: Thanks Jacques, I thought it was __bridge but wasn't certain.  I'm still not sure how the retain cycles work with CF, but I'll get to it one of these days.

Comment: A quick string search through the link you provided shows we can't use the word "new" but I didn't see anything about using the word "get."  Did you confuse the two or did I miss something?

Comment: I admit that I'm not 100% certain that `get` causes problems with ARC (I've been meaning to look into it), but that is a very long-standing naming convention in Cocoa. See `-[NSArray getObjects:range:]`, `-[NSString getCharacters:range:]`, and others.

Comment: For the purposes of Objective-C naming conventions, I doubt get and Get are equivalent. But like Jacques, I'd suggest renaming the method.  Just `UUID` would be a fine name.

Comment: See my answer for a more updated version of this which uses a built-in function and only one line of code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22839680/1091402

Comment: Why don't you have to `CFRelease(string);`?

Comment: Because you don't want to _just_ release it, @BenC.R.Leggiero, you want ARC to take ownership. The name `CFBridgingRelease()` makes this clear, and, as the doc quote I included says, it's equivalent to `__bridge_transfer`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you no longer need to support iOS prior to 6.0 at this point, you can skip all the Core Foundation UUID stuff and just do this to get a fresh one:

```
NSString * uuidStr = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

Comment: I ended up using this in other apps a while later.  Forgot all about this post.

Comment: Does this return a string formatted exactly like `CFUUIDCreateString`?

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero Yes. The textural format for a UUID is standard.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
NSString *UUID = CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFUUIDCreate(NULL)));
```

Comment: This requires you to already have a `CFUUIDRef`, which is not the case in the OP's code.