# Security issues and parsing data iPhone to Server

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, xcode, security

I have an iPhone that uploads `jpg` images to folder `'uploads'` on a remote server. This is done using a asynchronous method on the iOS, which connects to a PHP script. The PHP script then handles the image. The PHP script is simple and looks as follows :

```
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://iphone.zcentric.com/uploads/{$file}";
}
```

How can I improve the security to know that it is the correct iPhone that is connecting to the PHP script?. Also, how can I create a folder that has an unique name to the iphone device so the images are stored inside it, rather than in the '`uploads`' server?. e.g. the iPhone connects to the PHP Script, the script verifies the iPhone and gets an unique identifier (i'm not sure what that unique identifier can be, perhaps imei?), and creates a folder e.g. `M234SFDFS/image.jpg`

Comment: Very related: [Security threats with uploads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads/11061577#11061577)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bunch of data from individual phones (with just a couple of lines of code)

Add them as URL variables when you access the PHP page.

I am looking at a more elegant way to do this myself, and I am stuck using php. I had to go to script variables, but I think I am going to have to move to something a bit more advanced like websockets.

~ Dan

Answer (score 0):

If you have any kind of user management on the server side you can go with a simple **HTTP Basic Authentication** to check the user credentials and increase the security.

Moreover I would suggest to **send a unique id** from your iOS app to the server to identify the same iOS device. To do this check the thread [How to create a GUID/UUID using the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427180/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-using-the-iphone-sdk) which shows you how to create your own unique id instead of using the device id (which is deprecated).