# How to generate UUID in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to get a UUID in objective c, like in Java UUID is used to generate unique random numbers which represents 128 bit value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a GUID/UUID using the iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427180/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-using-the-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Try:

```
CFUUIDRef udid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
NSString *udidString = (NSString *) CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, udid);
```

**UPDATE:**

As of iOS 6, [there is an easier way to generate UUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUUID/UUID). And as usual, there are multiple ways to do it:

Create a UUID string:

```
NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

Create a UUID:

```
[NSUUID UUID]; // which is the same as..
[[NSUUID] alloc] init];
```

Creates an object of type `NSConcreteUUID` and can be easily casted to `NSString`, and looks like this: `BE5BA3D0-971C-4418-9ECF-E2D1ABCB66BE`

**NOTE from the Documentation:**

> **Note:** The NSUUID class is not toll-free bridged with CoreFoundation’s CFUUIDRef. Use UUID strings to convert between CFUUID and NSUUID, if needed. Two NSUUID objects are not guaranteed to be comparable by pointer value (as CFUUIDRef is); use isEqual: to compare two NSUUID instances.

Comment: If you are using iOS 6, you can use NSUUID: NSString * uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

Comment: on line 1, `CFUUIDRef udid` should probably be `CFUUIDRef uuid` to avoid potential confusion of UDID (Unique Device Identifier) with UUID (Universally Unique Identifier)

Answer (score 10):

Swift version of [Raptor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352436/382879):

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
```

Answer (score 6):

```
+ (NSString *)uniqueFileName
{
    CFUUIDRef theUniqueString = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUniqueString);
    CFRelease(theUniqueString);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't just leave code without explanation, no matter how straightforward it is

Comment: Errr, not sure why you selected my particular reply to comment on a year and a half later XD.

Comment: I didn't realize it was 1.5 years old.. Oh well, it does work nicely though.. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
-(NSString*) myUUID()
{
    CFUUIDRef newUniqueID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    CFStringRef newUniqueIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueID);
    NSString *guid = (__bridge NSString *)newUniqueIDString;
    CFRelease(newUniqueIDString);
    CFRelease(newUniqueID);
    return([guid lowercaseString]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use CFUUID for iOS 5 or lower version and NSUUID for iOS 6 and 7.
for making it more secure you can store your UUID in keychain

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString*)generateGUID{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string];
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't useful for the community. Please look at [answer]

Answer (score -2):

For Swift 5.0, Use this,

```
    let uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(nil)
    let uuidStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidRef)
    let uuid = uuidStringRef as String? ?? ""
```