# Whats the difference between UID and UDID?

Tags: android, ios

What is the difference between `UDID` and `UUID`? I know that `UDID` stands for `U`nique `D`evice `ID`entifier and `UUID` is `U`niversally `U`nique `ID`entifier but I want to know what role or functionality each one plays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This explains it well: [Differences between UDID and UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872233/differences-between-udid-and-uuid)

UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier), what you call UI -  An id that's per app. It's also per install so if a user reinstalls the app it will be different.

UDID (Unique Device Identifier) - Is unique to your phone, it's used by apple mainly and is universal between apps.

Comment: That link is a good find; you should vote to close / flag this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @RoboticCat Good idea! Sadly don't have the reputation, although I should just tough it out and get it.