# I am using UUID to get Unique code from iOS Devices but while uninstalling or deleting and re-installing id Changed

Tags: ios, swift, uuid

I am using UUID to get Unique code from iOS Devices but while uninstalling or deleting and re-installing id Changed.. 
Suggest Without saving to Keychain and ASIdentifierManager.

`let deviceId = (UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!`

But in android - ANDROID_ID working fine

Note :Keeping the apple privacy and security

Comment: currently using for device = "ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier" but is also changed when formatting the ios device or resetting ....please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can store UUID in SSKeychain which will be there forever.
See the below code:

```
class func createUUID() -> String
{
    let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String
    var strApplicationUUID = SSKeychain.password(forService: appName, account: "incoding")
    if strApplicationUUID == nil {
        strApplicationUUID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
        SSKeychain.setPassword(strApplicationUUID, forService: appName, account: "incoding")
    }
    return strApplicationUUID!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when app is uninstall and install new app then you get unique code is different that also define in documentation of apple.

you may try

```
let UUID = NSUUID.UUID().UUIDString
```

for unique uuid Code.

Answer (score 0):

Addition @sagar's answer which yes **UUID** is unique for app every install basis. but you may want to use **UDID** which unique for everydevice. You can check also this 
 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21872479/3112591) from another question. it explains better. It might help.