# Storing integer that all mobile users can access

Tags: ios, database, amazon-dynamodb

I want to make a database for an iOS application consisting of groups that can have the same name. I am hosting my database on AWSDynamo.

Since multiple groups can have the same name, I was planning on having a groupID as the hashkey, unless someone can suggest a better method.

My main problem is storing an integer that will be the number of groups. This is so that when a user creates a new group the number will be incremented and the new group will get that number as its groupID.

How can I store an integer in such a fashion that all users can access it from the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UUID – Universally unique identifier

You can use a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (String) as your groupID in your groups table, and use conditional writes (PutItem, UpdateItem) to handle the extremely rare case where there is a collision. If you create a UUID for a new group where the UUID already is assigned to another group, you will get a ConditionalCheckFailedException so you can retry with a new UUID. You don't need to use an incrementing sequence to uniquely identify groups.

Comment: Actually a UUID is *not* a String but a 128-bit value, more of an unimaginably large number. For presenting a UUID value we create a String representation of a UUID in a canonical format using [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) characters and 4 hyphens. Like this: `de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014`. The spec for UUIDs requires lowercase hex, but many implementations of UUID generators violate this rule. iOS provides a facility for generating UUIDs; see [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352418/how-to-generate-uuid-in-ios).

Comment: As for collisions in generated UUID values, that is *not* a practical concern.  In a proper implementation of a UUID generator, collisions are virtually impossible, and I mean "virtually" in the most extreme sense. Even more so if using the original Version 1 (MAC address & date-time).

Comment: I did say extremely unlikely. Otherwise, you still raised valid points.