# Does the use of identifierForVendor reject my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect

In my project I am using identifierForVendor for unique key for identify iOS device. Will it be approve by Apple or not? Is there are any way to identify iOS device uniquely?

Comment: ya apple will approve,but UDID is dynamic

Comment: Thanks... @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Apple will approve your app. `identifierForVendor` is the way to go after Apple stopped approving apps using UDID. Note that `identifierForVendor` will be the same for all of your apps per user (if a user has more than one of your apps installed, all of these apps will return the same identifierForVendor).

Another way to go is to create [custom UDIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352418/how-to-generate-uuid-in-ios).

Answer (score 0):

Apple won't reject your app. It is the current way to uniquely identify a device that have installed your app. But if the user un-installs your app (all apps) and installs again, the `identifierForVendor` will return an entirely different UUID.

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value
>   changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can
>   also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing
>   an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app
>   stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully
>   handle situations where the identifier changes.

Reference : [UIDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)