# iPhone Regex for GUIDs

Tags: iphone, regex, hex, guid

I was searching around finding some easy regex for iPhone to validate if a NSString is in a valid Hex format, containing only characters from 0-9 and a-f. The same for GUID's. Or is there already a function built in to check if a GUID is valid?

I only found some posts about creating GUIDs. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/427521/633945) SO answer is creating GUID's in the format I'm using them.

Sample GUID

```
ADD2B9F7-A699-4EF3-9A70-130B92154B11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simplify Zaph's correct answer, just add this method to a category on NSString:

```
-(BOOL) isGuid {
    NSString *regexString = @"[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}";
    NSRange guidValidationRange = [self rangeOfString:regexString options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
    return (guidValidationRange.location == 0 && guidValidationRange.length == self.length);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `NSCharacterSet`:

```
NSString *testCharacters = @"ABCDEFabcdef0123456789-";
NSCharacterSet *testCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:testCharacters] invertedSet];

NSString *testString1 = @"ADD2B9F7-A699-4EF3-9A70-130B92154B11";
NSRange range1 = [testString1 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:testCharacterSet];
NSLog(@"testString1: %@", (range1.location == NSNotFound) ? @"Good" : @"Bad");

NSString *testString2 = @"zDD2B9F7-A699-4EF3-9A70-130B92154B11";
NSRange range2 = [testString2 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:testCharacterSet];
NSLog(@"testString2: %@", (range2.location == NSNotFound) ? @"Good" : @"Bad");
```

NSLog output:

```
testString1: Good
testString2: Bad
```

or using REs:

```
NSString *reString = @"[a-fA-F0-9-]+";

NSString *testString1 = @"ADD2B9F7-A699-4EF3-9A70-130B92154B11";
NSRange range1 = [testString1 rangeOfString:reString options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSLog(@"testString1: %@", (range1.location != NSNotFound && range1.length == testString1.length) ? @"Good" : @"Bad");

NSString *testString2 = @"zDD2B9F7-A699-4EF3-9A70-130B92154B11";
NSRange range2 = [testString2 rangeOfString:reString options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSLog(@"testString2: %@", (range1.location != NSNotFound && range2.length == testString2.length) ? @"Good" : @"Bad");
```

For a more rigorous GUID match:

```
NSString *reString = @"[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}";
```

Comment: That's a pretty easy and reasonable answer. I'll accept, because it's super simple. But what about GUID's with the dashes in a wrong place? Example `ABCDE-A----A-------9` would also work but is not a valid GUID.

Comment: Added more rigorous GUID match.

Comment: @Zaph shouldn't range.location be zero for the rigorous match?