# How to get Mac address OR UDID in ios using any third party API?

Tags: ios, ios8

i Know that we can not use UDID after ios 6. also after ios 7 we get mac address as 02:00:00:00:00:00

So i am looking for any third party api which will give me this details

Thanks in advance

Comment: For what purpose you require this?

Comment: i am just playing with UDID and mac address and want to use them in my app. i am not going to upload it on appstore so need to get this details.

Comment: It is not possible to get UDID. You need to use identifier for vender. This vender identifier is same for all apps by same vender. In your case if use are using it in only one app then you can go for it.

Answer (score 0):

[FCUUID](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID) may be your choice.

Also you can [create a GUID/UUID using the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427180/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-using-the-iphone-sdk) and use KeyChain to store the UUID.